# Как вызвать несколько  функции в цикле?

Tags: android, циклы, java, функции

Добрый день 
Я начал программировать под андроид недавно вот пишу первую программу. я пишу интервал таймер точнее копироваю для опыта interval timer.
 вот столкнулся с одной проблемой
Как вызвать несколько функции в одном цикле for?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnstart;
    Button btnabout;
    EditText prep_time;
    EditText rest_time;
    EditText work_time;
    EditText rounds;
    TextView result_time;
    int work_time1 = 0;
    int prep_time1 = 0;
    int rest_time1 = 0;
    int rounds1 = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnstart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
        btnabout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnabout);
        prep_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prep_time);
        rest_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rest_time);
        work_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.work_time);
        rounds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rounds);
        result_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_time);

        btnstart.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnabout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void starttime() {
        work_time1 = (int) Float.parseFloat(work_time.getText().toString());
        prep_time1 = (int) Float.parseFloat(prep_time.getText().toString());
        rest_time1 = (int) Float.parseFloat(rest_time.getText().toString());
        rounds1 = (int) Float.parseFloat(rounds.getText().toString());
        //timer work
        CountDownTimer workCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(work_time1*1000, 100) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFunished) {
                result_time.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFunished/1000) + " s");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                result_time.setText(rest_time1 + "");
            }
        };

        //timer otdixa
        CountDownTimer restCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(rest_time1*1000, 100) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFunished) {
                result_time.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFunished/1000) + " s");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                result_time.setText(work_time1 + "");
            }
        };

        //timer podgotovki
        CountDownTimer prepCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(prep_time1*1000, 100) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFunished) {
                result_time.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFunished/1000) + " s");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                result_time.setText(work_time1 + "");
            }
        };

        prepCountDownTimer.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < rounds1; i++) {

            if (i != rounds1) {

                workCountDownTimer.start();
                restCountDownTimer.start();

            } else {
                result_time.setText("Kuttiktaim");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(view.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnabout:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.btnstart:
                starttime();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а где именно 
вы можете подсказать

Comment: мне кажется нужно начинать с основа java , и после этого браться за андроид

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){ //цикл
    firstFunction(); //первая функция
    secondFunction(); //вторая функция
    thirdFunction(); //третья функция
}
```